# Thread Make timed out Error when call Asmx webservice

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, web-services

In .NET winform application after  fire simple thread function then my  online service get timed out error and not working  when i remove the thread function service work fine

```
private void ValidateAsync()
{
    ThreadStart trs = new ThreadStart(ValidateData);
    Thread OnloadValidator = new Thread(trs);
    OnloadValidator.IsBackground = true;
    OnloadValidator.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    OnloadValidator.Start();            
}
```

I've test all option and change about threading.

This my simple sample code for call service

```
Myservice Srv = new Myservice ();
srv.gettest();
```

Comment: Why does that thread require an Single Threaded Apartment?

Comment: Ive added test only. Mta or sta .